# error in including library database.txt file in c++

Tags: c++

I am making a library management system and including text file which contains information of books and book allotment. But it is showing an error. I am having a database.txt file in which names of books and allotment of the book is given. please help...

my code is

```
    #include<iostream.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<fstream.h>
    #include "C:\Users\Ritesh Singh Chauhan\Desktop\librarydatabase.txt"
    char name[20];
    char book[20];
    char person[20];
    void searchBook()
{
 ifstream infile;
infile.open("librarydatabase.txt");
cout<<"enter name of book";
cin>>name;
infile>>name;
 cout<<name<<endl;
 infile.close();

}
void addNewBook()
 {
 ofstream outfile;
   outfile.open("librarydatabase.txt");
   cout<<"enter name of book";
   cin>>book;
   outfile<<book<<endl;
   cout<<"successfully added";
   outfile.close();

 }
 void allotmentList()
 {
  cout<<"enter name of person";
  cin>>person;
 }
 void exitLib()
 {
 //exit();
  }
 void main() 
 {
 clrscr();
  int number;
  cout<<"press 1 to search book"<<" "<<"press 2 to add a new book"<<" " 
   <<"press 3 to allotment list by person"<<" "<<"press 4 to exit";
   cin>>number;
  switch(number)
   { 
   case 1: searchBook();
    break;
   case 2: addNewBook();
   break;
   case 3: allotmentList();
   break;
   case 4: exitLib();
   break;
   default: cout<<"press number between 1 to 4";
    }

    [code is showing error and an error message is given in image][1]}
```

Comment: Error Library.cpp 4:Unable to open include file "c:\users\RITESH SINGH CHAUHAN\Desktop\librarydatabase.txt"

Comment: try running the C++ IDE  as an admin or you can change the directory of your code. Save it to some other drive  and you are missing the file operation mode like "r" , "w", "a"

Comment: You can not include file that is a data source! You should load it just like you doing this in line `infile.open("librarydatabase.txt")` Even if you will be able to include this file, there will be a compilation error.

Comment: @Marcin can you suggest me the edited code it would be really helpful.

Comment: You need to understand understand what `#include` _actually_ does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove following line from the code

```
#include "C:\Users\Ritesh Singh Chauhan\Desktop\librarydatabase.txt"
```

And 
change the line

```
infile.open("librarydatabase.txt");
```

to

```
infile.open("C:\\Users\\Ritesh Singh Chauhan\\Desktop\\librarydatabase.txt");
```

Comment: Or at least change `#include` to `#define MYFILE` and then `infile.open (MYFILE);`

Comment: after substituting the above code. Function search books and addbook is not working.can anyone tell why or share improved code.